# python - 2 цикла while true одновременно

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Как **одновременно** запустить **2 связанных цикла while true**?
Первый цикл - отвечает за бота, а второй - за небольшую консоль, команды из которой должны влиять на первый цикл.

Comment: Какой бот, пример команды.

Comment: discord бот на основе discord.py. Пример привести не могу т.к. там я свою систему команд в консоли делаю

Comment: Надоело уже за даром помогать людям, так что вот ссылка в помощь https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd-example

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing, queue, time, random

def loop_1(q, e):
    while True:
        try:
            i = q.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            print(None)
        else:
            print(i)
            if i == 3:
                e.set()
                break
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 20) / 10)

def loop_2(q, e):
    while True:
        q.put_nowait(random.randint(1, 5))
        if e.is_set():
            break
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 20) / 10)
   
def main(q, e):
    multiprocessing.Process(target=loop_1, args=[q, e]).start()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=loop_2, args=[q, e]).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    e = multiprocessing.Event()
    main(q, e)
```

out:

```
None
4
2
None
4
3

Process finished with exit code 0
```